# I get "TypeError: $ is not a function" when using "import * as jQuery"

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, javascript-import

I have the following JavaScript, which executes without any errors or warnings:

```
import * as jQuery from './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
window.$ = jQuery;
```

... but when I try to use my new `$()` function ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Hello!');
} );
```

... I get this error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

### Approach with Typings (Preferred)

The best way would be to use jQuery typings:

1. Install jQuery

   ```
   npm install --save jquery
   ```
2. Install Type Definitions

   ```
   npm install -D @types/jquery
   ```
3. And import it as following

   ```
   import * as $ from 'jquery';
   ```

   [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-curie-fm25f?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

---

### Quick & basic approach

Instead of doing

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```

go with

```
declare var $:any;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Zain! This gives me `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: jquery`

Comment: I have added the link for the demo can you please check, I am able to run it fine with 2nd approach

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine on your demo -- thank you for that. For some reason, it doesn't work when I run it locally. Strange.

Comment: Have you installed the dependency and @types/jquery as well? 
Can you create a minimal example on codesandbox.io where I can help you debug it?

Comment: Haha -- I've never used codesandbox before, and it looks like there's a pretty steep learning curve, as I can't even get their "vanilla JS" template to display text in the browser panel. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cloud-3njzd?file=/src/index.js

(Edit: It works in Chrome but not in Firefox. I'll keep tinkering a bit.)

Comment: So here's the result of trying to get jQuery to work in their "vanilla JS" template: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-perlman-hg80z?file=/src/index.js 

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're doing this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery;
```

It should be this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Also go with

```
declare var$: any;
```

instead of

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```